# gremlin server is not starting with orientDB

Tags: orientdb, gremlin, orientdb2.2, gremlin-server

**Summary**

gremlin server not getting started with orientDB

**description**

I am trying to connected gremlin server with orient db but not getting success. while i am trying to start the server it shows **Graph [graph] was successfully configured via [conf/orientdb-empty.properties].** after that it gives some **groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException:**  error.Below pictures will give you more clarity

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gremlin-users/YOmjLbl9ObY
followed this post

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if those OrientDB "WARNING" messages regarding memory are significant or not. You may want to deal with those separately as OrientDB and Gremlin Server both need JVM memory allocation and you might not want OrientDB taking the full heap.

The error you asked about however is the issue with groovy exception. It looks like you have a simple jar conflict on your path. That can happen sometimes especially if you use a version of a TinkerPop-enabled graph whose TinkerPop version does not match version of Gremlin Server.

My guess is that OrientDB is bringing in an older version of groovy, the 2.4.7 and Gremlin Server already has 2.4.11. You can resolve that pretty easily by examining the `ext/orientdb` directory in Gremlin Server (assuming that's where the OrientDB plugin installed itself - it should be obvious when you look in the `ext` directory itself). Remove the groovy 2.4.7 jars from both the `ext/orientdb/lib`and `ext/orientdb/plugin` directories. Do the same for other conflicts that you come across and things should work. If not, I think you'll have to ask a new more specific question about that particular issue.

Comment: thanks for the reply. the server is now getting started after the groovy files deleted but now while i am running the query some `serialization` error i got